# Prove if xy < 140 then x < 10 or y< 14 by Contraposition

Tags: solution-verification

I have the following proof for this statement -

> Assume $x$ and $y$ are both integers. Prove by contraposition, if $xy < 140$ then $x < 10$ or $y< 14$.

> Assume that $x ⩾ 10$ and $y ⩾ 14$, then $xy ⩾ 10\cdot14 = 140$

My attempt at a proof is as above, however my answer seems rather short, is this enough to be a valid proof? Is there any additions I should make?

Comment: +1 I regard your proof as valid.

Comment: You seem to be using $x,y$ and $m,n$ interchangeably.

Comment: I understand now. I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The contraposition of `if xy < 140 then x < 10 or y< 14` is :

```
if not(x < 10 or y< 14) then not(xy<140)
```

which is the same than

```
if (x >= 10 and y >= 14) then (xy >= 140)
```

(which is what you stated)

This proposition is true *because both of the inequalities concern real positive numbers*

There's no need in adding anything else.

Comment: You can also see it better by absurd : if (xy < 140 and 10 <= x) then xy < 14x and you can divide by x because its positive and not equal to zero. Hence y <14.

Comment: +1 Long way round, but still good detail.  No explanation why anyone downvoted.  Reminded of Star Trek (TOS) episode at the OK corral: (Spock): when the physical laws cease to exist, reality must be questioned.  What was the downvoter looking for, graphics?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the argument *is* that simple.

You just needed to fix the typos in your question using $x$ and $y$ throughout (or $m$ and $n$). I did it for you.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated